# Editing file name with name and created date via batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that renames all the files in the folder by its name and created date. For example >User file name change it to >User_13-06-2012. Please help me.

I have this code which just add the new date with the name.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\account folder"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do set today=%%a%%b%%c
for %%f in (*.*) do ren "%%f" "%%~nf_%today%%%~xf"
```

Thanks from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: previous answer was incorrectly showing modification time, not creation time.

This

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.*) do ( 
  for /f "skip=7" %%B  in ('dir /T:c "%%A"^|sort') do (
   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%C in ("%%B") do echo %%~nA_%%C-%%D-%%E%%~xA
  )
)
```

will spit out new names for your files formatted as per your req. Should it fairly easy to work from this.

**Note:** This assumes your date separator is '/' and **in general it's locale dependent**

Edit: as pure batch solution above is inherently unreliable below is equivalent powershell one liner  - it's faster, locale independent and easy to modify. I would recommend to use this instead if ps is available.

```
get-childitem | ? {$_ -is [IO.FileInfo]} | foreach-object {$_.basename + "_" + (get-date ($_.CreationTime) -uformat "%d-%m-%Y") + $_.extension}
```

Comment: Isn't `%%~tA` date modified, not date created?

Comment: @BaliC - Thanks, of course you're right! I will redo and re-post in a moment

Comment: Thanks WMZ, but this only show me the date on the CMD. I wanna edit change the file name with name_cratedDate. Could you please help me? Thanks.